# How do i get the instrumentation APK from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to firebase cloud testing.

I need to upload my application APK and instrumentation test APK, how do i generate the instrumentation APK inandroid studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the test (right click on the test -> RUN)

You'll then find your Test apk in app/build/outputs/apk directory

Comment: I get this error: apk/androidTest/dev/debug/app-dev-debug.apk does not exist on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Run One of the Intrumentation test case that you make for your app.

After Go to the below directory.

*Your project Name*\app\build\outputs\apk\androidTest

In these directory your .apk file available.